# winforms - Move control to another thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

is it possible to move a control or at least copy the control to another thread then the one it was created on. The reason being is I want the control to load entirely in a background thread and then once it's done loading I want to move the control to another thread. For example:

```
BackgrundworkRunasync(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e )
{
     var GetData = GetData();
     CreateControl mycontrol = new CreateControl() //Tyep of WindowsForm
     mycontrol.Data = GetData; 
     e.Result = mycontrol;
}

BackGroundWorkerComplete ( object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e )
{
   CreateControl con = (CreateControl)e.Result;
   con.mdiparent = this;
   con.Show();

//Of course this is a cross threading exception. Can I move this control to the current thread or even create a control in the current thread and do a deep copy? Optimally I just want to move the control to another thread, can you do this?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The control *must* be created on the main thread.

You should modify your code like that:

```
BackgrundworkRunasync(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e )
{
     e.Result = GetData();
}

BackGroundWorkerComplete ( object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e )
{
    CreateControl mycontrol = new CreateControl() //Tyep of WindowsForm
     mycontrol.Data = e.Result; 
   myControl.mdiparent = this;
   myControl.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not allowed. All controls must be serviced by single thread. It is the thread you used to create the window, usually first thread of the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can update controls from a seperate thread using Invoke.  Have a look here

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/47a4da96-1023-443a-983a-b41e68ca6a6c

```
Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate     
  {
    //use control
  });
```